# Regex replace textbox.text in secound winform freezes

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I'm having a problem, I have a winform that opens a different form, to type in numbers.
For every second input it has to append `:`
The problem is that it freezes the program.

This works:

```
txt.Text = Regex.Replace(txt.Text, @".{2}(?!$)", "$0");
```

This causes the winform to freeze:

```
txt.Text = Regex.Replace(txt.Text, @".{2}(?!$)", "$0:");
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it freezes the program?" In most cases, this means an exception is raised. What's the exception? If it simply gets trapped forever doing nothing, that's very odd.

Comment: I believe your first form freeze because of the second form ??

Comment: No exception, it just freezes.
Why should the second form make it freeze??

Comment: How large is your input? I couldn't fathom why it would freeze, unless the input is big enough that it takes time to re-render the result.

Comment: Input 2-8 characters

Comment: How do you trigger the code above? Is it possible that it is within a "TextChanged" event handler (or the like)? For me "freezing" sounds like a recursion issue

Comment: You input made me realize that i had forgot to subscribe to the event
`TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;`
so yes it was caught in a recursion.
THX for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong way

```
txt.Text = Regex.Replace(txt.Text, @".{2}(?!$)", "$0:");
```

Right Way

```
TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
String txt = textBox.Text;
textBox.text = Regex.Replace(txt, @".{2}(?!$)", "$0:");
```